# Finite non-empty open sets as a topological property

Tags: general-topology

Show that having nonempty open sets containing only finitely many elements is a
topological property. That is, if $X$ is a topological space that has nonempty open
sets with finitely many elements and $f \colon X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $Y$ has
nonempty open sets with finitely many elements.

I am really stuck on where to start here

If $f \colon X \to Y$ is a continuous map and Y has nonempty finite open sets, does $X$
have to have nonempty finite open sets?

My gut instincts tells me this isn't the case. Does this counter example work?

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology and $\mathbb{Z}$ with discrete topology. All open sets in standard topology are infinite since they are just open intervals. Obviously, the discrete topology has nonempty finite sets.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed counterexample will not be continuous. To see this, note that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and so if $f$ were continuous, its image $f(\mathbb{R})$ should be connected. However, the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology are the singleton subspaces, and $f$ is not constant.

You are right in thinking that continuous functions do not preserve this property. For example, the constant map $\mathbb{R} \to \ast$ is continuous, but $\mathbb{R}$ does not have finite open sets. In the same light, the constant map $c : \ast \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $c(\ast) = 0$ is also continuous.

You are missing a key hypothesis (which you have quoted!). You need to show that if $X$ has finite open sets and there exists **homeomorphism** $f : X \to Y$, then $Y$ has finite open sets.

Try to think why a homeomorpshism should preserve both open sets and 'finiteness'. Spoilers below,

> Take $O$ finite (non-empty) and open in $X$. Since $f$ is a homeomorpshim, we know that it is an open map, and so $f(O)$ is an open set of $Y$. Moreover, this set is finite as $f$ is bijective. Note that we actually only need $f$ to be open for this to work, as we always have $|f(O)| \leq |O|$.

Comment: Alright, so if we define f: R -> {1}, where f(x) = x, would this work? Also, I am not quite understanding the last part. So if we say F is a finite nonempty open set in X, then f(F) is open in Y by def of homeomorphism. But why must it be finite? Why does this follow from bijectivity?

Comment: @nerdeagle24 If $f$ is bijective, $f(O)$ has the same amount of elements that $O$. But we dont even need that, suppose that $O = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. Then $f(O) = \{f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)\}$ has at most $n$ elements (they may repeat if $f$ is not injective. If we assume $f$ heomeo, then they will not).

Comment: (cont.) Regarding your first question, the only function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \{1\}$ (continuous or not) is the function defined by $f(x) = 1$ for all real $x$. This does not preserve the "finite open set property", but is is not a homeomorphism so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: I only need to have a continuous function so this should be sufficient, right?

Comment: Sufficient for *what*? The statement you are trying to prove is... true, so you will not find a counterexample. It is not true that continuous functions preserve this property (as shown in my answer) but you are proving this for *homeomorphisms*.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the fact that $f$ is a bijection for the finiteness part.